# How to display in fullCalendar a dayGridMonth like a timeGrid?

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

The main difference between `timeGrid` and `dayGrid` views is that the former has a box as representation instead of a line. Here there is the `dayGridMonth` (a `dayGrid` without boxes):

[image]

instead, the same with `timeGridWeek` looks like:

[image]

I need a month view that shows boxes with full text for each event. Something like a `timeGridMonth`. How can I get it with fullCalendar v5?

**Added**: This is a month view in fullCalendar v1. I am looking for something similar to this that shows full text on events:

[image]

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventDisplay and set it to "block" I would think. Always make sure you have a good look through the documentation

Comment: Thanks @ADyson, but this option creates 1 line boxes, so when the text is long it is not complete. What I'm looking for is something like it used to exist in fullCalendar v3 or previous where each box size is determined by its content.

Comment: There was never such behaviour in fullCalendar 3's month view either - demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/BaLgaGa . Did you have some customisation in your version to enable it?

Comment: Sorry, you are right @ADyson, I wasn't using v3, I have checked and it was v1. I have added an image to the post from my current v1. It is not customized at all, its just the basic version of fullcalendar v1.

Comment: I see. From what I can see the heights are fixed by the calendar's CSS. You could try to amend them but I suspect that could create other problems. There's no way to solve it through the API. Either you experiment with customising the CSS or you completely fork the dayGridMonth view's code and write your own version. I don't know why it was changed after v1, perhaps they thought it would have a neater appearance. You could always make a feature request to get it back again, or at least the option to show it on multiple lines.

Comment: Another UX possibility is to have short descriptions deliberately, and then have a popover which appears when the event is hovered (or clicked) if you prefer, which provides more detail about the event - that's something people do commonly with fullCalendar. Bootstrap popovers are popular, or tooltip.js

Comment: That second option is no possible (I already have popups). I am afraid that the unique option I have is to make my own view from scrach or adjust the CSS. I'm gona try..

Comment: If you already have popups then why can't you add the information there? Anyway I would try adjusting the CSS before you go down the custom view route, it's likely to be a lot simpler. If your requirement isn't urgent (or not essential immediately) you could always make a feature request to get an option for this to be added to fullCalendar. And since it's open source you could speed up the development by contributing code yourself. Details of how to do these things are on the fullCalendar website

Comment: My customers wants to view the full event name without having to move the mouse over the box. I've found the CSS that control the boxes: 
.fc-daygrid-event {
    white-space: normal !important;
}

.fc-h-event .fc-event-time {
    overflow: unset !important;
}

Comment: This plus the 'block' in the calendar config, does the magic :)

Comment: You might want to add this as the answer... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a result similar to v1 `monthView`view, you have to change two small pieces of code.

1. In the config, you have to set the `eventDisplay` to `block` as suggested by @ADyson in comments ([ref](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventDisplay)).
2. In the stylesheet, you have to add this:

   .fc-daygrid-event {
   white-space: normal !important;
   }
   .fc-h-event .fc-event-time {
   overflow: unset !important;
   }

With this two small changes, you'll have the expected result:

[image]